# apche24 redirects http://www.domain-name.com/common to http://images.domain-name.com without creating subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtualhost

I want use `http://images.domain-name.com` instead `http://www.domain-name.com/common` . I don't want to create any sub domain or sub directory with the name of `images` as used in the first URL.

All the images are located inside `/www/sites/domain-name/common/`. Without moving images from where they are currently located to sub domain or sub directory. 
Current URL for Images which are being loading `http://www.domain-name.com/common`

New URL should be `http://images.domain-name.com`

Can some one help me to solve this.

Comment: you need to create a virtual host and you can use this link to learn how to do it    https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: @DhavalChheda I don't wanna create any directory for this purpose. I want to use images with mentioned URL.Because Images are already located inside specified directory as you can find that in question. Without moving image files from their current location, i want to access "http://images.domain-name.com".

Comment: you are not creating another directory .. you are creating a subdomain ( virtual host )